# Reinforcement learning, what are time-dependent MPDs?

Tags: terminology, markov-process, reinforcement-learning

What are time-dependent MDPs? Does it mean, in every time step $t$, the agent should train a policy function $\pi_t$? If so, is it possible to train $\pi_t$ at time step $t$?

Comment: I'd ask the CS page, but a time-independent policy function is one that does *not* depend on time. One example setting where such policies arise is in infinite-horizon Markov decision processes (stationary policies).

Comment: @ErikM, sorry, I mean time-dependent, not time-independent.

Comment: Downvoter and close voters: please explain.

Comment: @ErikM This question is very much on topic here.

Comment: Reinforcement learning is a standard topic within machine learning. This is very much on topic here. I'm voting to reopen. (cc, @FranckDernoncourt)